# Text alignment with php and mysql

Tags: css

I'm having an issue when it comes to aligning the text of my sql result, I have a standard format that i have to follow. I have aligned it to the best of my ability, but the next row of results seem to move up a tiny bit. i have a image in the back ground and using that image as a template to display the data in the right format.

[Snap shot http://www.vijayredyadav.com/img/help.jpg](http://www.vijayredyadav.com/img/help.jpg)

as you can see in the image above each row of results moves up just a tiny bit.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {echo 

`'<div style="float: left; margin: 4px 9px 3px 8px; padding-left: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; height: 13px;">'.'<font size="1">'.$row['date'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<div style="width: 30px; float: left; margin: 4px 15px 3px 17px;">'.'<font size="1">'.$row['type'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<div style="float: left; margin: 4px 7px 3px 6px; width: 46px;">'.'<font size="1" >'.$row['uav_id'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<div style="float: left; width: 22px; margin-left: 26px; margin-top: 4px;">'.'<font size="1">'.$row['appt'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<div style="float: left; margin-left: 26px; margin-top: 4px; width: 51px;">'.'<font size="1">'.$row['ops_id'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<div style="float: left; margin-left: 18px; margin-top: 4px; width: 36px;">'.'<font size="1">'.$row['p1'].'</font>'.'</div>'.
'<font size="1" style="float: left; margin-left: 28px; margin-top: 4px;width: 36px;">'.$row['s1'].'</font>';
if($row["dn"] == 'Day'){

echo'<img src="/img/tick.gif" style="float: left; margin-left: 21px; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 29px;">';


}elseif($row["dn"] == 'Night'){

echo'<img src="/img/tick.gif" style="float: left; margin-left: 51px;  margin-top: 2px;">';

//echo'<font size="1" style="float: left;">'.'NIGHT'.'</font>';

}
echo '<font size="1" style="float: left; margin-left: 28px; margin-top: 4px; width: 17px">'.'N/A'.'</font>'.
'<font size="1" style="float: left; margin-left: 28px; margin-top: 4px; width: 48px;">'.$row['tolatype'].'</font>'.
'<font size="1" style="float: left; margin-left: 16px;; margin-top: 4px;">'.$row['remark'].'</font>'.'<br>';
}
```

if anyone can help that would be great thank you

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with PHP or MySQL. It is about CSS.

Comment: If it's `tabular` data, then why not use a `<table>` instead of trying to emulate a table with divs.

Comment: Also you should separate the style from the markup, and the `<font>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: You could do something like this for the `<table>` - http://jsfiddle.net/6pu5P/1/

Comment: have you tried increasing the height of the `<div>`?

Comment: use `height` and `line-height`.

Comment: hi i got it to work thank you to everyone for there help i created a table and it worked like a charm i just wanted to know if anyone could help me with a mysql question i was wondering if it is possible to add (+) two fields which are both formatted as time together